# Need to check which one of following grammar is correct

Tags: grammar

I need to check which of the following has correct grammar

Basically I have to create new web page, I am asking query that can I go doing same

> 1: Have we to make a new page for the same?
>    2: Shall we make a new page for it?
>    3: Should we make new page for it?

Comment: Do you mean "I am asking if I can go on doing the same thing"? Of your three alternatives, (2) and (3) are both acceptable. (1) is grammatical, but no native speaker would express it like that.

Answer (score 1):

All three are correct and mean almost the same thing. It is more a question of formality and intonation.

I have never hear anyone talk like (1). We do no use that in speech often.

The two last ones are correct but (2) has a more distant and formal tone.

You  should use (3), it is the type of language people expect to hear.